# Alu architecture of a Hack Computer

Tags: computer-architecture, logic, arithmetic, cpu, digital-circuits

I'm currently studying the ALU architecture (of a Hack computer) and how it works.
As part of my assignments, I have been asked the following question:

If we want the ALU to compute the function y-1, what should be the value of the zx (zeroed) and nx (negated)?

a. zx = 1, nx=1

b. zx = 0, nx=1

c. zx = 1, nx=0

d. zx = 0, nx=0

From a graphic provided by my textbook "The elements of computing systems" written by Nisan, N., & Schocken, S. (2005):

[image]

to produce y-1, both zx and nx should be "1", but I'm not sure it's the correct answer.
Could someone help me to understand which one is the correct answer?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think this is answerable with the information provided -- it will likely depend on the specific architecture, which is not described in this question.

Comment: @D.W. 
Thank you for your comment.
More specifically, I'm studying The ALU of a Hack computer (architecture). Would this help?

Comment: (The question seems to be about nand2tetris.org's *Hack computer*, the control signal $zx$ to mean *zero input x*, $nx$ to mean *negate input x*. The tables I found are weird in not showing *don't care* about  $nx$ where $zx$ is true/1 (same for input y).)

Comment: @greybeard Yes, this is correct, it's the nand2tetris.org's Hack computer. The Alu's truth table is the following:

https://media.cheggcdn.com/media%2Fef8%2Fef8ee0d1-f74d-465e-b97d-2bc29a2ae7a4%2FphpHhlsFW.png

Does it help?

Comment: @greybeard Thank you for your suggestion, I will certainly follow your advice.
About the "truth table", it's actually how they call it from the textbook.